# Duplicate symbol in C using Clang

Tags: c, duplicate-symbol

I am currently working on my first "serious" C project, a 16-bit vm. When I split up the files form one big source file into multiple source files, the linker (whether invoked through clang, gcc, cc, or ld) spits out a the error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _registers in register.o and main.o for inferred 
    architecture x86_64
```

There is no declaration of `registers` anywhere in the main file. It is a `uint16_t` array if that helps. I am on Mac OS 10.7.3 using the built in compilers (not GNU gcc). Any help?

Comment: Maybe you inadvertently defined it in a header ?

Comment: @PaulR it is in a header, that is the only way I can get the main function to see it.

Comment: @isf Well, thats where your duplicate comes from. The header is included in `main.c` and `register.c`, so your array exists two times.

Comment: @PaulR gah. Thanks for pointing out my noob mistake. Oh well, I have to learn some time. I have to look at K&R better. Thanks.

Comment: You want a *declaration* in the header, but the *definition* of the array should be in exactly one translation unit (which typically means in one .c file). Use the `extern` keyword to make a declaration of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have gotten some sleep, now I'll make some changes and try to make it all work.

Answer (score 15):

It sounds like you've *defined* a variable in a header then included that in two different  source files.

First you have to understand the distinction between *declaring* something (declaring that it exists somewhere) and *defining* it (actually creating it). Let's say you have the following files:

```
header.h:
    void printIt(void);           // a declaration.
    int xyzzy;                    // a definition.

main.c:
    #include "header.h"
    int main (void) {
        xyzzy = 42;
        printIt();
        return 0;
    }

other.c:
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "header.h"
    void printIt (void) {         // a definition.
        printf ("%d\n", xyzzy);
    }
```

When you compile the C programs, *each* of the resultant object files will get a variable called `xyzzy` since you effectively defined it in both by including the header. That means when the linker tries to combine the two objects, it runs into a problem with multiple definitions.

The solution is to declare things in header files and define them in C files, such as with:

```
header.h:
    void printIt(void);           // a declaration.
    extern int xyzzy;             // a declaration.

main.c:
    #include "header.h"
    int xyzzy;                    // a definition.
    int main (void) {
        xyzzy = 42;
        printIt();
        return 0;
    }

other.c:
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "header.h"
    void printIt (void) {         // a definition.
        printf ("%d\n", xyzzy);
    }
```

That way, `other.c` knows that `xyzzy` exists, but only `main.c` creates it.